# remote desktop who is connected from where?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I know how to use qwinsta/query to find out who is connected to a given machine via Remote Desktop, but the info printed out doesn't tell me from which machine it is the connection coming from.  How can I get that info?

Comment: My first thought: Use PsExec or something similar to get a remote shell on the system, then use `netstat | find "3389"`. I'm not sure if there's another Microsoft tool that will get you the information more gracefully - especially if you happen to be limited to the command line.

Comment: That seems to work, and yes command line as even qwinsta is being ran remotely, and by that I mean ran netstat via winexe and grepping locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following command to check out the machine remotely connected.

```
psexec \\remoteMachine -u user -p pswrd netstat | find "3389"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, as Iszi commented above.  And I'm not coming from a Microsoft OS, so no psexec.

Comment: I've downloaded `PsExec` and it's working fine, but what's the intention of `netstat | find "3389"`? On my system, this is not giving any information. Is there another way to determine who is accessing a system?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `PsLoggedOn -l \\<remote_PC>`? The `PsLoggedOn` tool comes with PsExec installation.

Comment: That only tells who is logged on locally, not if it is a remote desktop connection, neither where that remote desktop connection comes from, which was the question.